# why i am not able to print data with for loop in c/c++?

Tags: c++

I updated my code still it is not working.
i am using simple c++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    void put_data()
    {
        cout<<"hello\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
A a[3];

//working
a[0].put_data();
a[1].put_data();
a[2].put_data();

//Not working
for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
{
    cout<<a[k].put_data();
}

return 0;
}
```

whe i try to access object array with directly it works well, but when i try to access it with for loop not working.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't even be able to compile this program.  The expression `cout << a[k].put_data()` should give you a compilation error because `put_data` has `void` as its return type.  Surely your compiler showed you that error message somewhere; make sure you know how to read compiler errors.

Answer (score 5):

This is unnecessary:

```
cout<<a[k].put_data();
```

when the `put_data()` method has the `cout` contained inside it. It's also invalid because `put_data()` is `void` and doesn't `return` anything that `cout` could work with.

You probably mean to do just:

```
a[k].put_data();
```

Comment: Answers should generally be formulated as an answer, not as a question to the OP. Note that you can [edit] your answer to improve it.

Comment: It seems someone else was kind enough to reformulate your answer for you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the assist Ted!  Appreciate it, and including the note on void.  I was thinking along the lines of "this is someone's homework" so wasn't sure about answering outright or using a guiding question.  Also, I'm new to this ;)